# Converting one object into similar with an additional field in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, type-conversion

So I have a case with a case class that used internally and another one that used for external API. And I am trying to convert from one to another.
Of course, I could just code every parameter by hand and get it over with, but that is long annoying and I have to update this code every time I add or remove a field.
What I am trying to do it this:

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

trait STrait {
  def id: Option[Int] = None
  def addressId: Option[Int] = None
  def name: String
  def about: Option[String] = None
  def numberOfStudents: Option[Int] = None
  def websiteUrl: Option[String] = None
  def mediaId: Option[Int] = None
  def slug: String
  def shortDescription: Option[String] = None
  def ready: Boolean
  def classrooms: Option[Int] = None
  def yearEstablished: Option[String] = None
  def displayCopyright: Boolean
  def createdAt: DateTime = DateTime.now
  def updatedAt: DateTime = DateTime.now
  def deletedAt: Option[DateTime] = None
  def createdBy: Option[String] = None
  def updatedBy: Option[String] = None
  def dliNumber: Option[String] = None
}

case class S(override val id: Option[Int] = None,
                  override val addressId: Option[Int] = None,
                  override val name: String,
                  override val about: Option[String] = None,
                  override val numberOfStudents: Option[Int] = None,
                  override val websiteUrl: Option[String] = None,
                  override val mediaId: Option[Int] = None)
    extends STrait

case class SAPI(override val id: Option[Int] = None,
                     override val addressId: Option[Int] = None,
                     override val name: String,
                     override val about: Option[String] = None,
                     override val numberOfStudents: Option[Int] = None,
                     override val websiteUrl: Option[String] = None,
                     override val mediaId: Option[Int] = None,
                     address: Option[Address] = None)
    extends STrait {

  def fromSchool(school: S): SAPI = {
    val schoolApiData = S.unapply(school).get :+ Option.empty[Address]
    (SAPI.apply _).tupled(sApiData)
  }
}
```

I am using `shapeless` to add a parameter to match params list in the applied tuple. But, for some reason, instead of being a tuple this `S.unapply(school).get :+ Option.empty[Address]` is considered as `prepend.Out` instead.
The weird part is, if I do the same in a console and assign this line to a `val` the type of that val is tuple.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
Something really interesting.
Apparently, the code compiles fine. But, IntelliJ complains:
[image]

Comment: I copied your code and, after cleaning out a few typos and excess stuff, it all compiled and ran. (IntelliJ worksheet) It's a bit curious that you put the `fromSchool()` method in the `class` (instance) definition instead of the `object` code where it would seem to make more sense.

Comment: @jwvh See my update

Comment: Sometimes the syntax highlighter gets confused and flags code that compiles without error. There is probably a command to make it re-evaluate but I haven't bothered to track it down.